# Is there a programming language which takes indent as containment markers? (and if so, which)

Tags: programming-languages, indentation

I'm wondering if such a syntax (borrowed from C#, mind you) is used by a programming language, i.e., tabs for containment, without any "End" directive.

```
class Character
    static string Name;
    static int Level;
    static Inventory Inventory;
    static double Health;

    Character(string name, int level)
        this.Name = name;
        this.Level = level;
        this.Inventory = new Inventory(this);
        this.Health = 1;

    void Die()
        this.Health = 0;

class Inventory
    Character Parent;
    List<Item> Items;

    Inventory(Character parent)
        this.Parent = parent;
```

Comment: Python ????????????

Comment: Close the question, and go to bed.

Comment: There is no option for "Stupid question" when closing... :/

Comment: @Lazo The only stupid question is the one that isn't asked? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Python
2. Haskell
3. Occam

These are the ones I know of.

Comment: Haskell uses brackets, no? And I don't know Occam (time to Google).

Comment: @Lazlo: I didn't take the grammar into account -- I thought you said it was an example borrowed from C#? Just the significant whitespace thing.

Comment: No, you were right. I never use Haskell, to be honest. I'll just wait 8 minutes then accept this answer.

Comment: By the way, Occam gives me headaches trying to look at it.

Comment: for fun add CoffeeScript if you are doing client.

Answer (score 3):

One I know if is Python. Not sure if there are others around.

Answer (score 2):

Python.